# How to seek to the last offset in Kafka correctly?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to read Kafka topic from last offset, but I am not able to do it correctly:

In properties file I set these:

group.id=my_group
client.id=my_client
enable.auto.commit=true
auto.offset.reset=earliest
isolation.level=read_committed

Then the code:

```
consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props); // read properties
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1L));
consumerRecords.forEach(consumerRecord -> System.out.println(consumerRecord.offset());
```

I can see how offset is printed from 0 even if I have some items in topic.

In log file I can see this (shortened):

> [Consumer clientId=my_client, groupId=my_group] Finished assignment
> for group at generation 1:
> {my_client-f1678be7-ce6b-48e8-acf2-741ab28f7266=Assignment(partitions=[mytopic-0])}
>
> [Consumer clientId=my_client, groupId=my_group] Successfully joined
> group with generation 1 [Consumer clientId=my_client,
> groupId=my_group] Notifying assignor about the new
> Assignment(partitions=[mytopic-0])
>
> [Consumer clientId=my_client, groupId=my_group] Adding newly assigned
> partitions: mytopic-0
>
> [Consumer clientId=my_client, groupId=my_group] Found no committed
> offset for partition mytopic-0
>
> [Consumer clientId=my_client,> groupId=my_group] Resetting offset for
> partition mytopic-0 to offset 0.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? I tried some magic with seekToBeginning() + poll() + commitSync() + seekToEnd() and it somehow worked, but I think this should work by default.

Comment: I think I can see the problem now: could it be the auto.offset.reset flag set to earliest? I've followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/53562232/3467894 where "will start the consumer at the last committed offset" is mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

**auto.offset.reset=latest** ll solve ur problem

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#offset-management

Comment: Yes, that was it. We set the policy to earliest in past for some reason and it's causing troubles today.

Comment: This will only work if there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist anymore on the server. To cover the case when the consumer group has a valid offset on the server you'll have to advance the offset manualy. You can do it either by calling `seekToEnd` after subscribing or by providing `ConsumerRebalnceListener` which will itself seek to end when the partition is assigned. The later approach has the benefit of not having to manually specify partitions to seek to end on.